# What is the best cooling solution for ASRock C2750D4I Rack home NAS storage

Tags: processor, data-storage, cooling

I bought this bad boy today, but it runs kinda hot. If it gets hotter, is slows down its frequency.

http://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=C2750D4I#Specifications

Can you guys recommend me a fan that can keep it cool.

So far I found the Noctua A8 ( With 6 years of warranty ) that also fits perfectly on the fan slot I have in the case, blowing right on top.

http://noctua.at/en/nf-a8-pwm.html

Do you guys have a better option in mind. Price does not matter, as long as it's a good fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fan will do the job perfectly, as I installed it 2 weeks ago.

http://noctua.at/en/nf-a9-pwm.html

The CPU will not go over 48 Degrees C, no matter the load.